# Trying to get Heart Rate Variability from Polar H10 [Bluetooth Low Energy Sample UWP]

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, bluetooth

I am working with Polar H10 to get the Heart Rate Variability from it.

I am running [Bluetooth Low Energy Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs) from Microsoft.

I have used this sample to get the heart rates from another polar device (Polar OH1) and it worked fine.

But now I want to get the HRV from Polar H10. But BLE sample code is not really showing me the HRV Characteristic which it should just like heart rate.

These are the only characteristics I am seeing:

```
 // first layer keys are serviceUuid's
// second layer keys are characteristicUuid's
// with their respective name/description as values
{
    "1800"    /* Generic Access */                      : {
    "2a00": "Device Name",
    "2a01": "Appearance",
    "2a02": "Peripheral Privacy Flag",
    "2a03": "Reconnection Address",
    "2a04": "Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters"
},
"1801"    /* Generic Attribute */                   : {
    "2a05": "Service Changed"
},
"180d"    /* Heart Rate */                          : {
    "2a37": "Heart Rate Measurement",
    "2a38": "Body Sensor Location"
   // This is where it should show Heart Rate Variability //
},
"180a"    /* Device Information */                  : {
    "2a23": "System ID",
    "2a24": "Model Number String",
    "2a25": "Serial Number String",
    "2a26": "Firmware Revision String",
    "2a27": "Hardware Revision String",
    "2a28": "Software Revision String",
    "2a29": "Manufacturer Name String"
},
"180f"    /* Battery Service */                     : {
    "2a19": "Battery Level"
},
"6217ff4b-fb31-1140-ad5a-a45545d7ecf3" /* unknown */: {
    "6217ff4c-c8ec-b1fb-1380-3ad986708e2d": "unknown", /* read:true */ // value = 
     uInt16Array [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    "6217ff4d-91bb-91d0-7e2a-7cd3bda8a1f3": "unknown" /* write:true, 
     indicate:true, descriptors:{ descriptorUuid: "2902" }*/
 {
     /* 6172 */
     this service has all the numbers which I have no idea about. 
     Example: 10905, 10906, and etc.  
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what adjustments should I make to the code so that I can get HRV?

```
                 **EDIT::** 


           private static ushort ParseHeartRateValue(byte[] data)
    {

        // Heart Rate profile defined flag values
        const byte heartRateValueFormat = 0x01;

        byte flags = data[0];
        bool isHeartRateValueSizeLong = ((flags & heartRateValueFormat) != 0);

        if (isHeartRateValueSizeLong)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return data[1];
        }
    }
```

////AFTER UPDATING ABOVE METHOD//////

```
          private static ushort ParseHeartRateValue(byte[] data)
    {
        ushort offset = 1;
        // Heart Rate profile defined flag values
        const byte heartRateValueFormat = 0x01;

        byte flags = data[0];
        bool rr = (flags & (1 << 4)) != 0;
        if (rr)
        {
            int count = (data.Length - offset) / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {

                ushort value = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, offset);

                double intervalLengthInSeconds = value / 1024.0;
                offset += 2;
            }
        }
        bool isHeartRateValueSizeLong = ((flags & heartRateValueFormat) != 0);

        if (isHeartRateValueSizeLong)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 1);
        }
        else 
        {
            return data[1];
        }

    }
```

Comment: You shoudl read value from characteristic 2a37 of service 180d. Data format described there: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.heart_rate.xml

Comment: 2a37 only gives me integer heart rates like 71, 82, 89) which changes every two seconds.

Comment: Shoudl they be analog in digital device?

Comment: Yes they should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device you use follow the Heart Rate Bluetooth specification. So the data it sends should respect this standard. if you refer to [this documentation](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml), you will read the 0x2A37 characteristic, which you listed in your question, but you should not receive it as an int.

The different values given by the characteristic are listed in the documentation I linked. I think that you will be interested by the 'RR-Interval', which is given with a resolution of 1/1024 second.

You will need to retrieve the required bytes from your value. Be careful about the byte order. As the documentation states:

> The fields in the above table are in the order of LSO to MSO. Where LSO = Least Significant Octet and MSO = Most Significant Octet.

So you are looking for the last 2 bytes of the value, since the RR-Interval is an uint16.

Comment: RR interval is represented by 2 bytes which is UInt 16. So you are saying that I will need RR-interval to calculate the HRV? Not sure what you mean by "retrieve the required bytes from your value". I think it has something to do with the method from the sample BLE code I am using. (See edited question)

Comment: If I understant correctly, you need the RR-Interval to calculate the HRV. Search Google for 'hrv and RR-Interval' and you will find resources explaining this to you. Those are medical terms that I don't fully understand, so I won't try to explain them :)  About your question, I found an answer containing code written in C# used to retrieve the RR-Interval. Check the first answer (written by Daniel Judge) of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422218/bluetooth-low-energy-how-to-parse-r-r-interval-value

Comment: Okay so I have updated the above method using Daniel Judge's example (See above) but the question still remains. When I run it how do I see the RR-Value?

Comment: It is the intervalLengthInSeconds variable

Comment: I understand that but when I run the code am I supposed to see the RR-intervals ?

Comment: Because all I can get is heart rate every two seconds.

Comment: No, you need to put a breakpoint to check that the variable contains what you expect. After that it's up to you to use it as you want

Comment: So put a breakpoint on double intervalLengthInSeconds = value / 1024.0; ?

Comment: Yes. And see the value that it contains

Comment: I debugged it but it says The thread 0x3ff4 has exited with code 0 (0x0). and The thread 0x7eac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
format: 71 (this is heart rate) And every time it gives me different 0x(something)

Comment: And just to make sure that we are on the same page: I want to get the heart rate variability on UWP app just like the heart rates. You have seen this image already :[ https://ibb.co/m2tqrp ] Because eventually I want to get those variability values  on TCP Server.

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't help you more than that. I'm not used to work with this kind of stuff, so if it does not follow the documentation I don't know what's the issue

Comment: Okay tested again here are all the bytes: 0x10, 0x64, 0x41, 0x02, 0x50 and 0x02 @ Léo D

Comment: Hey @Léo D I think you might be able to help me with this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071796/using-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference