# Using Pass by value or Pass by Reference?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have two methods in my code. Below is one of them.

```
 private async void Characteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var newValue = FormatValueByPresentation(args.CharacteristicValue, presentationFormat);
        var message = $"Value at {DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss.FFF}: {newValue}";
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () => CharacteristicLatestValue.Text = message);
    }
```

And it's printing time (Value At) like [this.](https://ibb.co/m2tqrp)

Now, this is the second method.

```
 private static ushort ParseHeartRateValue(byte[] data)
    {

        const byte heartRateValueFormat = 0x04;

        byte flags = data[0];
        ushort offset = 1;

        bool HRC2 = (flags & 0x80) > 0; 

        if (HRC2) //if BPM is un uint16
        {
            short hr = BitConverter.ToInt16(data, offset);
            offset += 2;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We have 16:" + hr.ToString("x"));

        }
        else // if BPM is uint8
        {
            byte hr = data[offset];
            offset += 1;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("no 16:" + hr.ToString("x"));
        }



        bool ee = (flags & (1 << 3)) != 0;
        if (ee)
            offset += 2;



        // bool rr = ((flags & 1 << 4) != 0);
        bool rr = ((flags & 0x10) != 0);
        if (rr)
        {
            int count = (data.Length - offset) / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {


                ushort value = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, offset);

                intervals.Add((double)value); // Added
                if (intervals.Count > 190) // Added
                    intervals.RemoveAt(0);// Added 
                double mean = intervals.Average();// Added
                double sumOfSquareDiff = intervals.Select(val => (val - mean) * (val - mean)).Sum(); // Added
                double vrHR = Math.Sqrt(sumOfSquareDiff / intervals.Count); // Added

                double intervalLengthInSeconds = value / 1024.0;
                offset += 2;

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Heart Rate Variability:" + vrHR.ToString());
            }
        }
```

And it's printing the output like [this.](https://ibb.co/bFchLq)

But I want the Heart Rate Variability to print just below "Value at". 
How do I make that work ?

Should I do pass by value or reference? Any other suggestions ?

I asked more detailed question earlier here on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053718/heart-rate-variability-from-output-window-to-uwp-sample-window)

Comment: Please don't post pictures. Although I can see the image on the page that you've linked to, I can't see what you're talking about and I can't zoom the image.

Comment: From looking at the code I'm guessing that you're saying that the text being printed with `Debug.WriteLine` are not coming out consecutively. The only way you could guarantee them coming out consecutively is to put the two strings in a single call to `Debug.WriteLine`.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with passing by reference or by value.

Comment: Okay so when I run the code it opens a Bluetooth Low Energy sample window and giving me data as "Value At" . [ var message = $"Value at {DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss.FFF}: {newValue}";] This is why I added a picture to have a better understanding of what I am asking. But I also want the HRV to print on this windows as well. (Bluetooth low energy sample) not on the Visual studio compiler. (Again see the picture.) Now, "Value at" and "Heart Rate Variability" both are in different method. So this is why I was thinking maybe I could do pass by reference.

Comment: But can you show me what are you saying by " put the two strings in a single call to Debug.WriteLine" . I can try that.

Comment: Because I know that System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine will not print the data on Bluetooth Low Energy sample window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I want the Heart Rate Variability to print just below "Value at". How do I make that work ?

Your question completely was unrelated to 'pass by value or reference'. The `CharacteristicLatestValue` just is a TextBlock control on XAML page. It's used to show text on UI like the following:

`Value at 01:11:25:453: Heart Rate: 124`

If you want to show 'no 16:51', 'Heart Rate Varibility:661841865028902' etc these texts blow it like the following:

```
Value at 01:11:25:453: Heart Rate: 124
no 16:51
Heart Rate Varibility:661841865028902
```

You just need to add them after the `CharacteristicLatestValue.Text` like the following:

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () => CharacteristicLatestValue.Text = "Value at 01:11:25:453: Heart Rate: 124"+"\r\n"+ "no 16:51"+"\r\n"+ "Heart Rate Varibility:661841865028902"+"\r\n");
```

Comment: @ Xavier Xie - MSFT  heart rates and heart rate variability are coming from a polar H10 device. so I can't just write "Heart Rate Varibility:661841865028902"+"\r\n"); Because what about the private static ushort ParseHeartRateValue(byte[] data) then? because this is where I am calculating hrv by doing math.